# FDT compile swf modules and post compile

Tags: ant, air, fdt

I'm working on an AIR project which will require many swf modules. 
So I have a main project which loads swf files when needed and I need now to setup a project which only compiles a module swf, copies it to the main project and launches the main project.

First attempt was to use the launcher chain, but it didn't work. It seems so that the launcher chain doesn't execute external projects.

Second attempt was to use an ant script and to execute it after the swf compiled. I linked the script in FDTs "Post compile ant file", but this didn't work also. I'm only able to execute the ant file manually.

How can I setup a project which launches after compiling an ant file, which executes/launches another project?

Heres is an example which contains a main project and a module project: [fdt_ant.zip](http://solanomorales.com/fdt/fdt_ant.zip)
The ant file is in the module project included and should only copy the generated swf to the main project.

Comment: Elaborate on 'doesn't execute external projects' please. What is an 'external project'? Do you mean in a workspace which isn't open? You can always use Ant scripts in the launcher chain. FDT will wait for the Ant file to complete before executing the next link in the 'chain'

Comment: Hi Alan, with 'doesn't execute external projects' i mean another project in the same workspace. In the the zip file which i posted are two projects to reproduce my problem. Executing the "module" project i get in the console:
"Running: /Users/smorales/Desktop/fdt_ant/ModuleProject/ants/launch.xml"
But it never runs the other project.

Comment: Could you pose a screenshot of your launcher chain and launcher(s).